# Spring boot NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'com.epam.uc.calendar.AudienceRepositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'databaseDataBuilder'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'com.epam.uc.calendar.DatabaseDataBuilder'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

How can I solve this problem? I can't autowire my class into test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class AudienceRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    private AudienceRepository audienceRepository;
    @Autowired
    //This one
    **private DatabaseDataBuilder databaseDataBuilder;**
}
```

And class, it's bigger, but other fields with same pattern (final properties and method calling this objects):

```
@Component
public class DatabaseDataBuilder {

    private static final AudienceBuilder audienceBuilder = new AudienceBuilder();    

    public List<Audience> buildAudiences() {
        return audienceBuilder.buildAudiences();
    }
}
```

And idea see this bean and alt+insert will show it for me, but test can't find it... But again, it can find repositories...

Comment: Are both classes under a scannable package?

Comment: What does this have to do with rollback as stated in the title of your question?

Comment: [spring NoSuchBeanDefinitionException](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+NoSuchBeanDefinitionException&oq=spring+NoSuchBeanDefinitionException&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.974j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: about roll back sorry, changed name. I added component scan and it working now, but i rly do not understand why he finding repositories in "package com.uc.calendar" and not finding DatabaseDataBuilder in "package com"